# Factorial Programme in C lang showing different outputs in Turbo C++ and mobile apps (Turbo C++ output is wrong)

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
    int i,fact,a;
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    for(i=1;i<=a;i++){fact=fact*i;}
    printf("%d",fact);
    return 0;
}
```

Image is output of Turbo C
The above code when compiled and run in Turbo C++ gives output 16048 for 5 while Visual Studio gives output 120 for 5 which is correct.
Please help me out with this... **Thanks**

Comment: `fact` needs to get initialized (to '1').

Comment: Close to a typo: you failed to initialize `fact`: `int i, fact=1, a;`...

Comment: How is this question off-topic? It clearly contrasts expected behaviour with actual behaviour.

Comment: You should not be learning C++ with Turbo C++ — it is too old.

Comment: ... and you should format your code properly. It's much easier to work with properly formatted code.

Comment: Just to explain the 16048 output: in your non-initialized fact variable was a garbage value, one of the following 8 numbers: 1226, 9418, 17610, 25802, 33994, 42186, 50378, 58570. While calculating the factorial of 5 you multiplied this garbage value by 120. For example, 1226 * 120 = 147120. In hexadecimal notation it's 0x23EB0. In Turbo C++ all integers are 2-bytes long, so this value was actually truncated to the last 4 hex digits: 0x3EB0, which is 16048 in decimal. Same is valid for the remaining 7 numbers.

Answer (score 2):

you need to initialize `fact`:

```
int main()
{
    int i,fact=1,a;
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    for(i=1;i<=a;i++){fact=fact*i;}
    printf("%d",fact);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable `fact` is not initialized, which means that the program has undefined behaviour; perhsaps you are lucky for the case of the correct result.